# openssl command for mac not working in windows

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I've got this command that doesn't want to run in windows:

openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config <( cat server.csr.cnf )

it doesn't like the <  in this part:  <( cat server.csr.cnf )

any tips?

thanks!

Comment: This isn't about programming, but the `<( command[s] )` construct, called process substitution, is a feature of some Unix (including MacOSX) shells; it does not exist in either CMD or PowerShell in Windows. You can get ports of Unix shells to Windows, or in this case since what you want to substitute is actually just a fixed file, use that file's name as the argument: `... -config server.csr.cnf`

Comment: Thank you so much!